# React + typescript inheritance and extending property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am creating a component which will be extended in future, for that i need to make it more generic.

I have a requirement something like below.

I have a class Base which accepts properties of type 'cell' and 'phone'.

I want to extend that in NewBase class and support new property newType.

The error I am getting is

> [ts] This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"cell" | "phone"' and '0' have no overlap.

I am not getting enough ideas to extend the interface to support the new class
Please Help...

```
export interface IBaseType {
    type: 'cell' | 'phone' 
} 
export class Base extends React.Component<IBaseType > {
    public render() {
        const { name, type } = this.props;
        return (() => {
            switch (type) {
                case 'cell': return <h1>Cell</h1>
                case 'phone': return <h1>Phone</h1>
            }
        })()
    } 
}

interface NewType extends Omit<IBaseType, 'type'>  {
    type: 'newType' | IBaseType['type']
 }

class NewBase extends Base {
    constructor(props: NewType){}
    public render(){
       if(this.props.type === 'newType') {
          return <h1>Hi i am new type</h1>
       }
       return super.render();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not ```Component```'s signature for generics. If you peek in the typedef file you'll see it's ```React.Component<Props, State>```. Also, Facebook [recommends composition over inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `this.props` is determined by the props type argument you pass to `React.Component`.  In this scenario where `NewBase extends Base` and `Base extends React.Component<IBaseType>`, the type of `this.props` is still `IBaseType`, which explains the error.  If you want to be able to define subclasses of `Base` that have different props types, you'll need to add a type parameter to `Base` for the props type.  Something like this may work for you:

```
interface ICommonType {
    type: string;
}
export interface IBaseType {
    type: 'cell' | 'phone' 
} 
export class Base<P extends ICommonType = IBaseType> extends React.Component<P> {
    public render() {
        const { name, type } = this.props;
        return (() => {
            switch (type) {
                case 'cell': return <h1>Cell</h1>
                case 'phone': return <h1>Phone</h1>
            }
        })()
    } 
}

interface NewType extends Omit<IBaseType, 'type'>  {
    type: 'newType' | IBaseType['type']
 }

class NewBase extends Base<NewType> {
    public render(){
       if(this.props.type === 'newType') {
          return <h1>Hi i am new type</h1>
       }
       return super.render();
    }
}
```